# I cannot access my controller of my new Magento module (tutorial help)

Tags: magento

I am making a Magento module which is enabled, and my cache is off.

Using this tutorial...
http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-create-controller-36

Here's the controller I was asked to use in `app/code/local/Pfay/Test`.

```
class Pfay_Test_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
   public function indexAction ()
   {
     echo 'test index';
   }
   public function mamethodeAction ()
   {
     echo 'test mymethod';
    }
}
```

However when I go to `magento/Pfay/Test/index` in my web browser, I get a 404 page, not the controller.

Comment: In what folder did you place your controller file?

Comment: Can you post your config.xml please

Comment: `magneto/app/code/local/Pfay/Test/controllers`

Comment: Done! Looks fine to me. https://gist.github.com/ff27d11634bf39577e62

Comment: That's your `app/etc/modules/Pfay_all.xml`. We need to see `app/code/local/Pfay/Test/etc/config.xml`.

Comment: We need config.xml not etc/modules/Pfay_all.xml

Comment: Here it is. https://gist.github.com/e108d5f4344a01635c66

Comment: @desbest - please see answer to issue below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the example code that you are copying and pasting, there are spaces in betweeen the following tags in the Pfay_All.xml file:

```
<active> true </active>
<codePool> local </codePool>
```

Remove those spaces so the tags look exactly like this:

```
<active>true</active>
<codePool>local</codePool>
```

Also, the path you are using should be `/test/index` or `/test`  and not `/Test/index`  - i.e. no uppercase T in Test

Comment: Nice catch re whitespace, but I disagree that the URL should contain `Pfay`. Why should it?

Comment: Hi @JürgenThelen - apologies, copy and paste artefact!  I'll update the answer :) +1 your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Try any one of the below codes.

```
magento/Test/index or magento/Test or magento/test
```

The namespace is only for grouping the modules.

Comment: replace "routeurfrontend" by "test" in that XML

Comment: I've just done that now. But `magento/Test/index` still shows a 404 not found page.

Comment: "test" is your module name...
Clear cache once and try, I hope it works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12698/discussion-between-sankar-raj-and-desbest)

Answer (score 1):

**Some mistakes found in the tutorial**

The tutorial says to use `Test` in the url but there should be no uppercase in the url, just lowercase.

Another mistake in the tutorial is that the `<routeurfrontend></routeurfrontend>` tags should instead be `<test></test>`. You can update this in `local/Pfay/Test/etc`.

indexController.php should instead be called IndexController.php *(note the capital i)*

*Also read the other answers. The other answers are useful because the person who wrote the tutorial is bad at English, so it can be confusing to read. You'll find a 3rd mistake corrected in them, so look up.*